# Comparing files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

If I have two different class/layout files in a project. Is there any way I can compare which lines are different using Android Studio?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Select them both by selecting one, holding down `ctrl` (or `command` for mac) and clicking the second file, right-click, Compare Files.

[image]
[image]

Comment: And what about layouts? The XML files doesn't seem to have this one

Comment: @Nabin Works exactly this way for *any* files.

Answer (score 10):

Go to file name in project then press `control` then select `Compare File` and select another file you wish to compare.

Seperate window will open up showing differences by colour contrast.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! This question has already been answered. Please do not post a new answer unless it is really different from the original one, or the original one is outdated.

Comment: This is different from the original one, and I think it's better for some situations.